# NodeJS Mongodb Connection Error "undefiend"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, undefined

I am new to nodejs and mongodb. As you see below code, I am trying to connect mongodb by NodeJs but there is an

> "undefined" error

### Could anyone help me ?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');  
var mongodb = 'mongodb://localhost/yenidb';  
mongoose.connect(mongodb,{useMongoClient: true},function(err,err){

    if(err){
        console.log("mongoose error:" + err.log);
    }
    else{
        console.log("mongoose db connection status :" + mongodb)
    }

})
```

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring 2 different variables with the same name. Declare them with diffrent names:

```
,function(err,err)
```

for example:

```
,function(err,connection)
```